# How to dynamically generate imagebutton in div in ASP.net web application using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I'm using this code to dynamically generate imagebutton when retrieve  images in img folder in ASP.net Web Application Project.

```
private void OpenImage()
{
    foreach (string strFileName in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/img/")))
    {
          ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
          FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(strFileName);
          imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/img/" + fileInfo.Name;
          imageButton.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
          imageButton.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
          imageButton.Style.Add("padding", "10px");
          imageButton.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imageButton_Click);
          Panel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);
     }
 }
```

Now I want to display this within div tag that also generate dynamically. Any Suggestions Guys?

Comment: What is your question or problem? Does your code add a imageButton or not?

Comment: No the code generate imagebutton dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `<div>` (or any plain HTML element) in code behind with the [`HtmlGenericControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, and use that to wrap your `ImageButton` any way you want. For example:

```
private void OpenImage()
{
    foreach (string strFileName in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/img/")))
    {
        ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
        ...
        HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.Attributes["class"] = "my-class"; // or div.Attributes.Add("class", "my-class"); 
        div.Controls.Add(imageButton);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx @p.s.w.g for the help. :) Is there any way to give that div a class name??

Comment: ha ha work fine..! now I can preserve responsiveness of my template using that class. thanx again @p.s.w.g